# Count the number of empty spaces in front and back of the string

Tags: vba, excel

I am reading a file line by line in Excel VBA.

I have some strings for example,

```
"             ooo"
"         ooo                   "
```

I want to find the number of empty spaces in the front of the string. If I use Trim, it is removing empty spaces from both back and front of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Function test(s As String) As Integer
    Dim str As String
    str = "[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789]"

    Dim spaceCounter As Integer

    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If Not Mid(s, i, 1) Like str Then
            spaceCounter = spaceCounter + 1
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    test = spaceCounter
End Function
```

By popular request: Why use this function instead of `Trim`, `LTrim`, etc?

Well, to summarize [the full explanation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Remove-spaces-and-nonprinting-characters-from-text-023f3a08-3d56-49e4-bf0c-fe5303222c9d), not all spaces can be removed with `Trim`. But they will be removed with this function.

Consider this example (I'll borrow [PhilS' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37158801/4604845) for illustrative purposes):

```
Sub testSpaceRemoval()
    Dim str1 As String
    str1 = " " & Chr(32) & Chr(160) & "a"
    Debug.Print Chr(34) & str1 & Chr(34)
    Debug.Print NumberOfLeadingSpaces(str1)
    Debug.Print test(str1)
End Sub
```

Result:

```
"   a"  
2   
3
```

Here we can see that the string clearly contains 3 spaces, but the solution using `LTrim` only counted 2.

So, what to use?

Well, it depends. If you have a dataset where you know you won't get non-breaking characters, use `Trim` as much as you want! If you think you can get non-breaking characters, `Trim` alone will not be enough.

Characters to look out for are, quoted from the explanation linked above:

> leading, trailing, or multiple embedded space characters (Unicode character set values 32 and 160), or non-printing characters (Unicode character set values 0 to 31, 127, 129, 141, 143, 144, and 157)

`Trim` can remove `chr(32)` (as demonstrated above) but not `chr(160)`, because [32 is the regular space and 160 is a non-breaking space](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelfunctions/qt/080404_trim.htm).

If you're a stickler for covering your behind, consider this total solution:

```
Function cleanSpecialCharacters(str As String) As String
    bannedChars = Chr(127) & "," & Chr(129) & "," & Chr(141) & "," & Chr(143) & "," & Chr(144) & "," & Chr(157) & "," & Chr(160)

    str = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(str)
    str = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(str)

    For Each c In Split(bannedChars, ",")
        str = Replace(str, c, "")
    Next

    cleanSpecialCharacters = str
End Function
```

For OP's particular question, it would have to be a little more tailored.

Comment: that pattern can also be written as `[a-z0-9]` btw

Comment: I use that for regex, but didn't know you can use it with `Like` as well. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Yeah, it's one of the few things that `Like` allows thankfully!

Answer (score 7):

You could use the `LTrim` and `RTrim` functions. - I would assume that is faster, than looping through the string and doing character comparisons.

```
Public Function NumberOfLeadingSpaces(ByVal theString As String) As Long
    NumberOfLeadingSpaces = Len(theString) - Len(LTrim(theString))
End Function

Public Function NumberOfTrailingSpaces(ByVal theString As String) As Long
    NumberOfTrailingSpaces = Len(theString) - Len(RTrim(theString))
End Function
```

Comment: beat me to it, was typing this when yours popped up. Haha

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, LTrim removes space in front and RTrim removes space in back

Comment: Probably faster (and easier to implement), I agree. The downside is that for some use-cases it won't work (but doing character comparisons will). Of course, such use-cases might not arise at all depending on your dataset!

Comment: @Vegard: Sure, it works for chr(32) spaces only. For other characters, like non-breaking space, you have to use another solution, as you excellently illustrated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub blanks()    
    cadena = Cells(1, 1)
    i = Len(cadena)
    Do Until Mid(cadena, i, 1) <> " "
        If Mid(cadena, i, 1) = " " Then contador = contador + 1 
        i = i - 1
    Loop    
    Cells(2, 1) = contador
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub main()
    Dim strng As String
    Dim i As Long

    strng = "         ooo                   "

    i = 1
    Do While Mid(strng, i, 1) = " "
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    MsgBox "number of front empty spaces: " & i - 1
End Sub
```

or use `LTrim` function:

```
Sub main2()
    Dim strng As String
    strng = "         ooo                   "
    MsgBox "number of front empty spaces: " & Len(strng) - Len(LTrim(strng))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Does LTrim removes spaces only in front?

Comment: well you can see it by yourself by typing `Len(LTrim("         ooo "))` in the immediate window

Comment: but you discarded my answer... grrr! anyhow consider that @Vegard solution wouldn't account for characters like `"!'|£$` and such. while both mine solutions have no such restrictions. and `LTrim` one actually is very simple

Comment: @user3598756: While that is true, it's easy to add those to the list (just type them in). The downside of your and PhilS' answer is that `Trim` and its cousins can't remove all types of spaces.

Comment: I'm not the question-asker, so it's not up to me which question gets accepted. Just pointing out things to keep in mind. For many uses, `Trim` is perfectly fine. For others, it's not.

Comment: @Vegard, sorry I didn't notice it was not Jeevan answering. Anyhow both solution has been given: with and without `Trim` family